# What is "signature" in Google Play in app billing algorithm

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, rsa, google-play-services

Google play uses RSA algorithm for encryption/decryption. In the data returned from google play, there is a field named "signature".

```
Bundle containing the following key-value pairs
"RESPONSE_CODE" with int value, RESULT_OK(0) if success, other response codes on failure as listed above.
"INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST" - StringArrayList containing the list of SKUs
"INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST" - StringArrayList containing the purchase information
"INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST"- StringArrayList containing the signatures of the purchase information
"INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN" - String containing a continuation token for the next set of in-app purchases. Only set if the user has more owned skus than the current list.
```

I want to know what "Signature" and "Signature list" are which are  used in IInAppBillingService methods(`getSkuDetails`, `getBuyIntent` and `getPurchases`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the reference in the Android Developers website:

> INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE - String containing the signature of the purchase
>   data that the developer signed with their private key. The data
>   signature uses the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 scheme.

The purchase signature is a string created by signing the `INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA` with the private key associated with your developer account. You can use the signature to verify that the purchase data has not been tampered with by any way, and that the user actually purchased you app.

Since the signing process is done using a private key, verification should be made on a remote server and never on the device itself, so you will need to implement a verification server of your own if you wish to use this security feature.